# Mutt: change background color of expanded threads

Tags: configuration, mutt

Does anyone know how to change the color of the background of an expanded thread?

I know it's possible to change the color of the tree that shows the thread, but the color I put after the color indicating the tree (that I would expect to indicate the color of the  background) does not seem to do anything.

These settings give the same result:

```
index tree green black
index tree green red
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You’ll probably want to [check the colour options in the docs](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#color).

Answer (score 1):

I have experimented on my own system and it looks like this can be accomplished reasonably easily. My own mutt colours are pretty basic and I give these *in full* below:

```
### Colours ###

# (default, white, black, green, magenta, blue, cyan, yellow, red)
# (bright...)
# (color1,color2,...,colorN-1)
#
#---- --Mutt Colors for Black Background -------
#       Object      Foreground      Background
color   hdrdefault   yellow            black
color   quoted       blue              black
color   signature    blue              black
color   attachment   red               black
color   message      brightred         black
color   error        brightred         black
color   indicator    black             yellow
color   status       white             blue
color   tree         white             black
color   normal       white             black
color   markers      red               black
color   search       white             black
color   tilde        brightmagenta     black
color   index        blue              black ~F
color   index        white             black "~N|~O"
```

This gives a pretty basic thread display as the image below demonstrates:

[image]

Now with 2 changes to my existing config I change not only the foreground but the background colours as well for the expanded tree:

```
#       Object      Foreground      Background
color   tree        brightmagenta    yellow
```

And this gives the type of changes that you are after as I demonstrate with the image below:

[image]

Easy enough to do on my system and hopefully just as easy on yours :).

**Notes:**

- [Using Mutt with Gmail (POP3 over SSL)](https://www.andrews-corner.org/mutt.html): All the details from my own mutt setup including the full colour settings.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks a lot for your elaborate answer. Thanks to your answer I just found out that colorizing the background of the tree seems to works in mutt (also for me), but not in neomutt.

Comment: @shamiv Glad you have narrowed the issue down anyway :). I have not even really considered neomutt, particularly since the sidebar was incorporated into mainstream mutt. Any, good to meet a fellow mutt user :)